# Detox iOS create strong passwords feature

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

I'm wondering if there is a way to handle iOS create strong passwords feature. Probably disable it during test or something. Have checked docs, but found nothing. The problem I'm trying to solve is the following. While testing `Registration` screen I need to fill in password, but system window with `strong password request` appears and breaks my test.

Detox: `17.10.6`, RN: `0.63.2`

Comment: @LeoNatan any ideas?

Comment: Please open an issue on Github, and attach a screenshot. We'll continue discussion there. Thanks